# Why is this Tumblr share messing up the ampersand?

Tags: url, tumblr, sharing, url-encoding

I'm trying to have an ampersand in my caption that passed via a URL for Tumblr sharing.

I encoded the URL as `%26`, but it's outputting `&amp` in the caption.

If I try to use `&amp;` then it cuts off the rest of the caption.

Here is the URL I'm trying... You can just mess with the link to test it. Just wondering if anyone else has had problems with the way Tumblr decodes URLs or if I'm missing something obvious.

http://www.tumblr.com/share/photo?source=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.independent.co.uk%2Fincoming%2Farticle9269603.ece%2FALTERNATES%2Fw620%2Fcat.jpg&caption=This+cat+ate+an+M%26M=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.independent.co.uk%2Fnews%2Fworld%2Famericas%2Fpet-cat-puts-three-family-members-in-hospital-after-launching-frenzied-attack-9269612.html

As far as I can tell, it's an error on Tumblr's part... I'm encoding the `&` in the URL and Tumblr is decoding `%26` and encoding it for HTML as `&amp;` but sticking that escaped text inside a text field.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried everything I could think of and didn't find a workaround.

Comment: Ah ok. I ended up just leaving it too - if people want to change it themselves they can. Not ideal by any stretch. Thanks for the reply.